# Can I use 3d models I have created in Hexagon made by Daz 3d in commercial games?

Tags: copyright

I have been modelling in Hexagon for a while. I want to know if I can use 3d models I have created in hexagon in a commercial game as I have been planning to do one myself.

I don't want to  get in trouble for using Hexagon 3d models I have created in my commercial game.
I searched  Google but could not find the answers I was looking for. I went to the DAZ studio website but I could not find anything answering my question

Comment: Who are you concerned would hold rights to the model? It's entirely your own creative work, no? Or are you building on a sample asset made by someone else?

Comment: @DMGregory The Daz3d business model is somewhat complex. They appear to more or less give the editors away for free, but reserve the rights on usage & some of the content - in particular, meshes & textures. That said, I'm having a lot of trouble pinning down an official EULA or the like. Also, some of the editors have changed hands in terms of developers / publishers which also muddies the situation.

Comment: it is my creative work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information I could find about the [Daz3d Standard License Agreement](https://www.daz3d.com/interactive-license-info) states:

> Whenever you purchase 3D Content from Daz, it comes with certain
> rights that allow you to use that content. Some of those rights
> include the ability to:
>
> - Render Images
> - Render Videos
> - Render HDRIs> and/or Virtual Reality (VR) scenes
>
> Any of these that you produce and
> render out are completely owned by you, so you can use them
> commercially, modify them, sell them, or promote them, as protected by
> the End User License Agreement (EULA). This is because the end product
> is a render (your individual artwork) of the 3D Model, as opposed to
> the actual 3D Content.
>
> **When you should get an Interactive License:**
>
> Certain applications of models from Daz 3D require an Interactive
> License if you want to use that product in a particular way. Any app,
> game, or video game where the model changes depending on what a user
> does requires an Interactive License (example: if the 3D Model moves,
> bends, or walks based on an action the user of that app or game
> makes).

In general terms, it sounds like if you generated your meshes completely on your own, you should be in the clear to use them commercially. That said, this is not legal advice & you should consult a qualified legal professional.

Also, the information above doesn't include anything about textures / materials. I suspect the situation is similar - if you're using things you developed yourself, you're probably fine. If you're using materials from their marketplace, you'll need to check those rights seperately.

Comment: thank you for your answer

Comment: You are welcome. If you've this answer to be helpful, please consider [voting on it](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) & if you believe is the best solution to your problem, you can also mark it as accepted. Good luck with your game!